# Getting error when trying to encode message with Protobuf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, protocol-buffers

Protobuf generated:

```
# source: event.proto

require 'google/protobuf'

Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool.generated_pool.build do
  add_file("event.proto", :syntax => :proto3) do
    add_message "myapp.Event" do
      optional :name, :string, 1
      optional :entity, :enum, 2, "myapp.Event.Entity"
      oneof :event_data do
        optional :first_event_data, :message, 3, "myapp.Event.FirstEventData"
        optional :second_event_data, :message, 4, "myapp.Event.SecondEventData"
      end
    end
    add_message "myapp.Event.FirstEventData" do
      optional :id, :string, 1
      optional :to, :string, 2
      optional :from, :string, 3
    end
    add_message "myapp.Event.SecondEventData" do
      optional :metadata_url, :string, 1
    end
    add_enum "myapp.Event.Entity" do
      value :FIRST, 0
      value :SECOND, 1
    end
  end
end

module Myapp
  Event = ::Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool.generated_pool.lookup("myapp.Event").msgclass
  Event::FirstEventData = ::Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool.generated_pool.lookup("myapp.Event.FirstEventData").msgclass
  Event::SecondEventData = ::Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool.generated_pool.lookup("myapp.Event.SecondEventData").msgclass
  Event::Entity = ::Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool.generated_pool.lookup("myapp.Event.Entity").enummodule
end
```

Now in the console when I do

```
message = Myapp::Event.new(
        entity: :SECOND, 
        name: "started",
        event_data: {
          second_event_data: 
            Myapp::Event::SecondEventData.new(
              metadata_url: "local-dev-url",
            )
        }
      )
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from (irb):178
        2: from (irb):178:in `new'
        1: from (irb):178:in `initialize'
ArgumentError (Unknown field name 'event_data' in initialization map entry.)
```

I have tried different combinations and every time different error, I think I am organising my `message` incorrectly.

Any help would be appreciated greatly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, after lots of research, apparently I can't do it all at once. I need to create 2 or 3 seperate objects:
i.e

```
message = Myapp::Event.new(
        entity: :SECOND, 
        name: "started")
```

And then I can do this:

```
message.second_event_data = Myapp::Event::SecondEventData.new(
              metadata_url: "local-dev-url",
            )
```

Then when I encode it, `second_event_data` will sits under the `event_data`